why I failed to establish ICE connection when server and client run both locally?
Problem
I tried to create a WebRTC demo which accepts video and audio stream from client and streams video back to client.
After gathering ICE candidate, it failed to establish ICE connection. And ICE conection state is new all the time.
And now I can't determine which part of code went wrong. Therefore I came here to ask for help.
Python server-side code:
import os
import asyncio
import av
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from aiortc.rtcicetransport import candidate_from_aioice
from aioice.candidate import Candidate
from aiortc import RTCPeerConnection, RTCSessionDescription, MediaStreamTrack, RTCIceCandidate, VideoStreamTrack
from aiortc.contrib.media import MediaPlayer
import flask_cors
import flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(24)
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='eventlet', cors_allowed_origins="*")
flask_cors.CORS(app)

peers = {}


def RealRTCIceCandidate(candidateInitDict) -> RTCIceCandidate:
    candpref = 'candidate:'
    candstr = candidateInitDict['candidate']
    if not candstr.startswith(candpref):
        raise ValueError('does not start with proper string')
    candstr = candstr[len(candpref):]
    cand = Candidate.from_sdp(candstr)

    ric = candidate_from_aioice(cand)
    ric.sdpMid = candidateInitDict['sdpMid']
    ric.sdpMLineIndex = candidateInitDict['sdpMLineIndex']
    # XXX - exists as part of RTCIceParameters
    # ric.usernameFragment = candidateInitDict['usernameFragment']

    return ric


class VideoReceiver(MediaStreamTrack):
    kind = "video"

    def __init__(self, track: MediaStreamTrack):
        super().__init__()
        self.track = track

    async def recv(self):
        print("VideoReceiver recv")
        frame = await self.track.recv()
        return frame


async def consume_video(pc: RTCPeerConnection, client_id):
    print(f"Consuming video from client {client_id}")
    try:
        remote_track = None
        for i in pc.getReceivers():
            if i.track.kind == "video":
                remote_track = i.track
                break
        if remote_track:
            receiver = VideoReceiver(remote_track)
            pc.addTrack(receiver)
        else:
            print(f"No suitable video track found for client {client_id}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error consuming video: {e}")


@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    client_id = str(flask.request.sid)
    pc = RTCPeerConnection()
    peers[client_id] = pc

    @pc.on("track")
    async def on_track(track: MediaStreamTrack):
        print(f"Track received from client {client_id}: {track.kind}")
        if track.kind == "video":
            await consume_video(pc, client_id)

    @pc.on("icecandidate")
    async def on_icecandidate(candidate):
        print(f"ICE candidate received from client {
              client_id}: {candidate.candidate}")
        socketio.emit('icecandidate', candidate, room=client_id)

    print(f"Client {client_id} connected")
    emit('your_id', client_id)


@socketio.on('sdp')
def handle_sdp(data):
    client_id = str(object=flask.request.sid)
    if client_id not in peers:
        print(f"No peer connection found for client {client_id}")
        return
    pc: RTCPeerConnection = peers[client_id]
    sdp = RTCSessionDescription(sdp=data['sdp'], type=data['type'])

    print(f"Received SDP from client {client_id}: {sdp.type}")

    async def process_sdp():
        if sdp.type == 'answer':
            await pc.setRemoteDescription(sdp)
        else:
            await pc.setRemoteDescription(sdp)
            await pc.setLocalDescription(await pc.createAnswer())
            socketio.emit(
               'sdp', {'type': 'answer', 'sdp': pc.localDescription.sdp}, room=client_id)

    asyncio.run(process_sdp())


@socketio.on('icecandidate')
def handle_icecandidate(data):
    client_id = str(flask.request.sid)
    if client_id not in peers:
        print(f"No peer connection found for client {client_id}")
        return
    pc = peers[client_id]
    print(data)

    async def process_icecandidate():
        if data:
            await pc.addIceCandidate(RealRTCIceCandidate(data))

    asyncio.run(process_icecandidate())


@socketio.on('disconnect')
def handle_disconnect():
    client_id = str(flask.request.sid)
    if client_id in peers:
        pc = peers[client_id]
        asyncio.run(pc.close())
        del peers[client_id]


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>WebRTC with Flask</title>
  <script src="/static/socket.io.js"></script>
  <style>
    video {
      width: 640px;
      height: 480px;
    }

    #chatbox {
      width: 300px;
      height: 200px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    #message {
      width: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>WebRTC Video & Audio Chat</h1>

  <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay playsinline></video> <br>
  <button id="disconnectButton">Disconnect</button>
  <button id="connectButton">Connect</button>

  <h2>Chat</h2>
  <div id="chatbox"></div>
  <input type="text" id="message">
  <button id="sendMessage">Send</button>

  <script>
    let socket = null;
    const config = {
      iceServers: [
        {
          url: "turn:www.xiaokang00010.top:6212",
          credential: 'nb123',
          credentialType: 'password',
          username: 'cw'
        }
      ]
    };

    const remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');
    const disconnectButton = document.getElementById('disconnectButton');
    const connectButton = document.getElementById('connectButton');
    const chatbox = document.getElementById('chatbox');
    const messageInput = document.getElementById('message');
    const sendMessageButton = document.getElementById('sendMessage');

    function connect() {
      let socket = io('http://localhost:5001', {
        autoconnect: false
      })
      socket.connect()
      socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('Connected to server');

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
          .then(stream => {
            pc = new RTCPeerConnection(config);

            // Add local video track
            const videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
            const audioTrack = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
            pc.addTrack(videoTrack, stream);
            pc.addTrack(audioTrack, stream);

            // Handle remote tracks (video and audio from server)
            pc.ontrack = event => {
              console.log('New remote track received:', event.track.kind);
              if (event.track.kind === 'video') {
                remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
              } else if (event.track.kind === 'audio') {
                const remoteAudio = document.createElement('audio');
                remoteAudio.srcObject = event.streams[0];
                remoteAudio.autoplay = true;
                document.body.appendChild(remoteAudio);
              }
            };

            // Handle ICE candidates
            pc.onicecandidate = event => {
              if (event.candidate && event.candidate.candidate !== "") {
                socket.emit('icecandidate', {
                  'candidate': event.candidate.candidate,
                  'sdpMid': event.candidate.sdpMid,
                  'sdpMLineIndex': event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex
                });
              }
            };

            // Handle offer/answer negotiation
            pc.onnegotiationneeded = async () => {
              try {
                const offer = await pc.createOffer();
                await pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
                socket.emit('sdp', { 'type': 'offer', 'sdp': pc.localDescription.sdp });
              } catch (err) {
                console.error('Error during offer/answer:', err);
              }
            };

            // Handle server-side disconnection request
            socket.on('disconnect_command', (data) => {
              console.log('Server requested disconnect:', data.reason);
              if (pc) {
                pc.close();
                pc = null;
              }
              addToChat(data.reason, 'Server'); // Display disconnection message
            });

            socket.on('sdp', async (data) => {
              if (data.type === 'answer') {
                await pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data));
              }
            });

            socket.on('ice_candidate', async (data) => {
              const candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
                sdpMid: data.sdpMid,
                sdpMLineIndex: data.sdpMLineIndex,
                candidate: data.candidate
              });
              await pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
            });

          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.error('Error accessing media devices:', err);
          });
      });

      // Receive chat messages
      socket.on('chat_message', (message) => {
        addToChat(message, 'Remote');
      });

      socket.on('your_id', (message) => {
        console.log('Your ID:', message);
      })
    }

    let pc; // Your RTCPeerConnection instance

    // Function to add messages to the chatbox
    function addToChat(message, sender) {
      const messageElement = document.createElement('p');
      messageElement.textContent = `${sender}: ${message}`;
      chatbox.appendChild(messageElement);
      chatbox.scrollTop = chatbox.scrollHeight; // Scroll to bottom
    }

    // User-initiated disconnect
    disconnectButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (pc) {
        pc.close();
        pc = null;
      }
      socket.emit('disconnect_request'); // Inform the server
      socket.disconnect();  // Disconnect Socket.IO
    });

    // Send chat messages
    sendMessageButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const message = messageInput.value.trim();
      if (message) {
        socket.emit('chat_message', message);
        addToChat(message, 'You');
        messageInput.value = '';
      }
    });

    connectButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      connect();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>

I've tried to add a STUN server and even build a TURN server using coturn. But I've got WebRTC: ICE failed, your TURN server appears to be broken, see about:webrtc for more details . I thought that since it can't even work on localhost. So this is naturally worthless.

A full code repo is here: http://www.xiaokang00010.top:4001/xiaokang00010/webRTC-test
